# Dealing with a string as file input for a program within bash script

Tags: bash-scripting

Say I have tool X that accepts only files as input, is there any way to pass input to X as a string without having to write it to file then reading it within a bash script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution):

```
toolX <(echo "$var")
```

The file seen by the tool will look something like `/dev/fd/123`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But by trying it, it turns out that my tool needs a file with specific filename, so can I rename it and place it in current working directory instead of `/dev/fd/123 `?

Comment: Nope. Sounds like the simplest solution is to write your data to a file, or modify toolX